# How to specify the ciphersuite to be used in SSL session

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ssl, network-programming

I have created a socket on port 443 as in the following line:

```
socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(hostName, port);
```

Then, I wanted to see the enabled ciphersuites in this socket, I used:

```
String[] enCiphersuite=socket.getEnabledCipherSuites();
System.out.println("Enabled ciphersuites are: "+Arrays.toString(enCiphersuite));
```

Then, I want to pick only one ciphersuite that I want my application to use when creating handshake with the remote server. I did the following:

```
String pickedCipher[] ={"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"}; 
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(pickedCipher);
System.out.println("ciphersuite set to: "+Arrays.toString(pickedCipher));
```

Then I made the handshake, and checked the session ciphersuite:

```
socket.startHandshake();
System.out.println("Session ciphersuite is"+socket.getSession().getCipherSuite() );
```

But I found that the name of the cipher printed in the previous printout statement after the handshake (as I understand, this is the actually used cipher in the session) is not what I set earlier using `setEnabledCipherSuites()`

Why am I still not see my chosen ciphersuite is the used one ? and also, I also tried to `getEnabledCipherSuites()` and print it out after I `setEnabledCipherSuites` and found the list has not changed to what I have set. I am not sure when I print the enabled ciphersuite, is this list of ciphersuites depends on Java and always the same list, or depends on the client or on the server? Can any body explain ?

**EDIT:**
Before the handshake I only have the following lines:

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(); 
SSLSocket socket=null;
try {
socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(hostName, port);
socket.setSoTimeout(15000); 
socket.startHandshake(); //handshake
.
.
```

Comment: It is the suite of crypto options such as symmetric encryption algorithm.

Comment: I know what *a* cipher suite is. I asked you what *the* cipher suite is. The one that was actually negotiated. I also asked why you think you need to do this.

Comment: It is for testing & illustration purposes in a toy java application. The problem I described is general not inclusive for one ciphersuite. Ex: When I try to connect to hotmail.com, the session ciphersuite is: `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`. when I try to change it from my Java application to anything else, say: `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA`, and try to connect, again, the chosen ciphersuite for theis SSL session is: `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`. As far as I understand that setEnableCiphersuite() is going to use the ciphersuite I set. This is not working with me (in several examples).

Comment: Is there anything else in your code, before you call `startHandshake()` explicitly? Do you have a call to `getSession()` or are you trying to read/write using the I/O streams? (Either of these would initiate the handshake, possibly before you make the call to `setEnabledCipherSuites(...)`).

Comment: I edited my post and added the few lines before the handshake. There is no `getsession()` before the handshake. Only after it to print the sesison ciphersuite. After the handshake, I call: `socket.getInetAddress();` to get the IP. Then, I call: `socket.getSession().getCipherSuite();` to get the session cipher suite.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all SSL servers support all cipher combinations.

Comment: "duskwuff: that is true. some ciphers result in a message `connection reset`. But even those who are supported, the application does not gives any error but does not set the cipher.

Comment: @Bruno: I found out that I added `socket.getsession()` before the `setEnableCipherSuite()` in order to print out the enabled cipheres before setting them. When I removed it, the cipher has been set. why is that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I found out that I added socket.getsession() before the
>   setEnableCipherSuite() in order to print out the enabled cipheres
>   before setting them. When I removed it, the cipher has been set. why
>   is that ?

As documented in the [`SSLSocket` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html):

> The initial handshake on this connection can be initiated in one of
>   three ways:
>
> - calling startHandshake which explicitly begins handshakes, or
> - any attempt to read or write application data on this socket causes an implicit handshake, or
> - **a call to getSession tries to set up a session if there is no currently valid session, and an implicit handshake is done**.

If you call `getSession()` before calling `setEnabledCipherSuite()`, the handshake has already been done when you try to set the enabled cipher suites, so this session's cipher suite has already been selected.