# How to enable disabled cipher suites in Oracle JDK 1.7

Tags: java, java-7

My Java version is 1.7 and according to [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#footnote2-1) I see that some of the cipher suites are disabled by default from Oracle.

I want to use `SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA`which is a disabled cipher suite. How can I enable this disabled cipher suite?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943351/how-to-specify-the-ciphersuite-to-be-used-in-ssl-session

Comment: Improved readability

Comment: Bad idea, 1.7 supports TLSv1.2 and uses TLSV1 by default, use it or you will be vulnerable to attacks like Poddle.

Comment: Why do you think Oracle disabled them?

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://blogs.oracle.com/coffeys/entry/jdk_and_use_of_rc4 you should be able to do it as follows:

Using API method call:

```
sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String [] {
  "SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
  "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", 
  "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA", 
  "SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA", "SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA", 
  "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5", "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA", 
  "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"});
```

Or https.cipherSuites system property:

```
java -Dhttps.cipherSuites= SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA \
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,\
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,\
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,\
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,\
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,\
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,\
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV MyTLSApp
```